# Regexp in Pentaho

Tags: regex, pentaho

I have a regexp that works fine upon testing in online regexp sites. 
However when using it in pentaho it is not working properly.

Regexp

```
([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)
```

Sample input: select 1 from schema.table 
Wanted output: schema.table

Actual output by Pentaho: 
a.table

How do I correct and achive desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `\b([\w-]+\.[\w-.]+)`.

`\b` means word boundary, but the online regexp sites are right, it shouldn't be needed here.

---

#### Solution

Pentaho works well with regexp that matches the whole line.

```
^.* ([\w-]+\.[\w-.]+).*$
```

Comment: still doesn't work. this does not return any value in pentaho.

Comment: Then put a space instead of `\b`.

Comment: stil nothing. I've read that pentaho uses java regexp but I'm not sure how to convert my current regexp into java.

Comment: It works fine in here: https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html

Comment: true. but in pentaho regex evaluation step, it doesn't work. i swear pentaho is weird af.

Comment: `^(?:[\w]+ )*([\w-]+\.[\w-.]+)$`

Comment: hey. this worked! tho I have to tweek it a bit but it did the job. one thing tho. if my string is like this -- "with x as (select 1 from schema.table) select * from x" it doesn't work anymore. Also how do I tag your comment as answer?

Comment: `^.* ([\w-]+\.[\w-.]+).*$` There is tick to left of the answer.